# Lie symmetry methods of differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, symmetry

If we have a differential equation
$$
y^{(n)} = H( x, y, y', ...y^{(n-1)}) .
$$
And say we have its two infinitesimal generators admitted by this equation. What do I mean by the invariance of this equation with respect to these two infinitesimal generators and with respect two those two infinitesimal generators what happens to the equation ? For example if one of them is $ G_{1} = \frac {\partial}{\partial{y}}$ and the other is $ G_{2} = x\frac {\partial}{\partial{y}}$. What happens to the equation with respect to these infinitesimal generators?. 
Thanks for any sort of hints or help

Answer (score 3):

Let us first consider a simplified setting. Assume that in the two-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}(x)\times\mathbb{R}(y)$ you have a manifold defined by an equation
$$
\mathcal{M}(x,y) = 0\quad.
$$
This manifold is said to be invariant under the action of the differential operator $G$ of the form
$$
G = \xi(x,y)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + \eta(x,y)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \quad,
$$
if the following is true:
$$
\Bigl.G[\mathcal{M}(x,y)]\Bigr\rvert_{\mathcal{M}}
= \left.\left(\xi(x,y)\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{M}(x,y)}{\partial x} + \eta(x,y)\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{M}(x,y)}{\partial y}
\right)\right\rvert_{\mathcal{M}}
= 0 \quad.
$$
In the equation above we first 1) Act with the operator $G$ on the manifold $\mathcal{M}$, and then 2) Evaluate the resulting expression at the points of $\mathcal{M}$. Note that the expression $G[\mathcal{M}(x,y)]$ does **not** have to vanish trivially, it may happen that $G[\mathcal{M}(x,y)]\neq 0$.

Coming back now to the differential equation. Let us rewrite it in a more general form:
$$
F(x,y,y',\ldots,y^{(n-1)},y^{(n)}) = 0\quad.
$$
It can be understood as a manifold in the space $\mathbb{R}(x)\times\mathbb{R}(y)\times\mathbb{R}(y')\times\ldots\times\mathbb{R}(y^{(n)})$.

Since the line above contains not only $x$ and $y$, but also $y$'s derivatives up to the order $n$, it is not exactly the operator $G$ who should be applied to the line above. Instead, we need to introduce its $n$-th *prolongation* $\underset{n}{G}$. This will be operator of the form
$$
\underset{n}{G} = G + \zeta_{(1)}\partial_{y'} + \ldots +\zeta_{(n)}\partial_{y^{(n)}} \quad.
$$
**See Peter Olver's book "Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations" for details** on how to calculate the prolongations of operators.

In analogy with usual manifolds, the equation $F=0$ is said to be invariant under the action of $G$ (or, more precisely, its prolongation $\underset{n}{G})$ iff
$$
\left.\underset{n}{G}[F(x,y,y',\ldots,y^{(n-1)},y^{(n)})]\right\rvert_F = 0 \quad.
$$
Again, note that after applying $\underset{n}{G}$ to $F$ we evaluate the result at the points of $F$.

Sidenotes:

1. In certain (quite rare but still physical) cases the functions $\xi$ and $\eta$ depend not only on $x$ and $y$, but also on derivatives $y^{(k)}$. The most celebrated example of such a *generalized* symmetry is the Runge-Lenz vector.

   2.
   The knowledge of symmetries of the differential equation can be very helpful for integrating it. Good news is that finding them is a rather straightforward (but a bit technical and lengthy process). There's a very nice package for Mathematica which does this, it comes with **Brian Cantwell's book "Introduction to Symmetry Analysis"**.

Comment: This is very clear to me now. So now when I apply my $G_{1} $ and $G_{2} $  to H. How do I get rid of the $y $ and $y^{'}$ terms ?

Comment: When acting on $F$ with $\underset{n}{G}$, you treat all the $x, \, y, \, y', \ldots, y^{(n)} $ as independent coordinates, literally as in the case of a usual manifold in the intro example. Then, to evaluate $\underset{n}{G}[F] $ "on the manifold", you solve (algebraically) the original equation for one of the quantities $x, \, y, \, y', \ldots, y^{(n)}$ and substitute it into $\underset{n}{G}[F]$. With an equation written in the form you provided, it would be natural to simply substitute $H(\ldots) $ instead of $y^{(n)} $.

Comment: Yes but do I have to get something which has no $y$ and $ y^{'} $ terms after applying $G_{1} $ and $ G_{2} $.

Comment: No, why would you? The expression $\underset{n}{G}[F]$ may contain all sorts of $y$'s derivatives. However, if $\underset{n}{G}$ is a symmetry of $F$, this expression should vanish after "going on the manifold".

Comment: Actually I am reading the theorem that if the equation of the type above admits an $n $ dimentional abelian lie algebra then the equation is linearizable. I have $G_{1} $ and $G_{2} $ elements of that abelian algebra and then it says that from the invariance of the equation with respect to these generators the equation takes a form where the right hand side will not include the $y $ and $ y^{'} $ terms. Did I explain my question ??

Comment: Well, that's quite different from what you asked in the original question. Roughly speaking, if the DE admits for a solvable $r$-parameter Lie algebra of symmetries, you can integrate it $r$ times (see e.g. Section 8.10 in Cantwell). And, obviously, Abelian Lie algebras are trivially solvable. So, if you have two commuting differential operators, you can surely integrate the differential equation at least two times. Note that there are subtleties with low-order differential equations. For a quick review, I recommend to read the first two pages of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.03829).

Comment: The answer to your question on linearizability can be found in the [original publication](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X9090244A), see Theorem 1.

Comment: Thank you @ mavzolej. I am already reading the second reference you have given. It was nice to discuss with you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In general Lie symmetry methods for differential equations helps to construct complexe solution of DE from simple one , for example take the heat equation thanks to Lie theory we can construct the heat kernel from constant solutions